# single channel mode in spite of dual ram boards [8 + 16] GB

Tags: ram, intel

I have a Dell Latitude 3420 with Dual SO-DIMM RAM slots. 8GB came with the device and I plugged in 16 GB more thinking that "more RAM = more speed". Processor is 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1135G7 @ 2.40GHz.

But after installing the 16 GB RAM, my BIOS screen shows that I am running in "single channel mode".

I went to the BIOS expecting to see "Dual channel mode" under the Memory column since I have both the slots with plugged in with RAM boards [8 + 16]

**Q1.** Why is this so?

**Q2.** Will there be noticeable performance upgrade in dual channel mode? [My use case is web-browsing, speech synthesis, speech-to-text conversion using some algorithms and speech models, audio editing, occasional video editing]

Answer (score 0):

1. For dual-channel you need to have pairs of equivalent DIMMs; since yours have different sizes, your system operates in single-channel mode.
2. If your new DIMM supports the same speeds as your initial 8GiB DIMM, at least you won’t have lost any performance, and if your working set exceeds 8GiB, adding memory will result in a significantly faster system.

   Whether dual-channel mode would bring noticeable additional performance improvements depends on what you use your system for. Web browsing probably wouldn’t benefit much, but video editing might. You’d have to try it with another matched DIMM to see...

Comment: Yes. I haven't lost anything for sure. What do you mean by "and if your working set exceeds 8GiB ? " Do you mean the total installed RAM [8+16]?